# Disable p:selectBooleanCheckbox with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

How can I disable `<p:selectBooleanCheckbox>` component using JavaScript?

My goal is to prevent user from changing value of one selectBooleanCheckbox while another is changed during ajax request time (which change values in managed bean).

My simplified code :

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="..." value="..." widgetVar="abcde">
    <p:ajax listener="..." update="..."/>
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>

<p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="..." value="...">
    <p:ajax listener="..."  update="..." onstart="alert(document.getElementById('j_idt14:locationChoice2_input').disabled);document.getElementById('j_idt14:locationChoice2_input').disabled=true;alert(document.getElementById('j_idt14:locationChoice2_input').disabled)" />
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

`j_idt14:locationChoice2_input` id is the id of my first `<p:selectBooleanCheckbox />` component.

alert() functions dsplay `false` and after `true` so my component is well disabled.

However, it stays with the same render event if it's disabled.

Is the only way to be changing manually CSS classes to match disabled state ? Can `widgetVar` help me ?

nb: I want to change immediately the aspect of the component so I don't use the JSF `disabled` attribute, I have to use JS.

Comment: maybe if there a way to skin blockUI component to render it transparent but effective ?

Answer (score 1):

I answer my own question.

I put inside simple `panelGrid` my 2 `selectBooleanCheckbox` and apply `blockUI` on this `panelGrid` :

```
<p:blockUI block="panelToBlock" widgetVar="block" />

<h:panelGrid id="panelToBlock">
   <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="..." value="..." widgetVar="abcde">
      <p:ajax listener="..." update="..." onstart="block.show()" oncomplete="block.hide()" />
   </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>

   <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="..." value="...">
      <p:ajax listener="..."  update="..." onstart="block.show()" oncomplete="block.hide()" />
   </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>

</h:panelGrid>
```

`blockUI` has a default opacity value to `0.3` but I don't want to see it, I just want to disable my 2 `selectBooleanCheckbox` so I change the value of the generated id to `0` at runtime with JS :

```
$(window).load(function() {

   $('#j_idt14\\:j_idt23_blocker').css('opacity', 0);

}
```

and that's all.

Now when ajax request is made, these 2 checkboxes values can not be changed.

Hope this helps